# Mozilla Fennec Android not deploying on the device

Tags: android, mozilla, fennec

I'm currently working on Mozilla Fennec project.

Visit: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Fennec/Android

I have done all the steps one by one but when I'm building and deploying it on the device, it is not deploying on the device, though building was successful for all the times I have tried.

Visit: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Fennec/Android#Build

Please help me with this, there is no error on the console. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: No I'm not getting any error message. The build is clean and no deployment is happening on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have any other installation of the same application already in the device?
If yes, try uninstalling it first and try again. Might be an issue with signing certificate mismatch.

Comment: I don't have firefox installed on the device. The build is clean without any error.